# Magento product delete not working

Tags: php, magento, product

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have encountered a problem when deleting products. I create 20 products in a clean install of magento using the product import routine. The products where assigned to categories, and had images associated with them. The products displayed perfectly.

I then went in to the back end and deleted the products by selecting them from the product grid and choosing delete. This worked fine on the face of it and the products disappeared from the products grid.

I then attempted to re-import the products using the same format import file with some slightly different descriptions ect (SKU's were the same as previously) and I get an error saying that the SKU must be unique.

I have attempted creating a simple product in the back end with several of the now deleted SKU's and I get the same error - sku must be unique.

I have noticed that if I go into the category within the back end the deleted products are still listed against the category - I cant un-associate them as the products are not visible in the product list.

The products are not visible within the store,and I have tried the following:

- refreshing the indexes and deleting the cash multiple times
- Using the mage api to try deleting the phantom items - this just errors as stock item not found
- Tried using the Mage and Soap API's to re-create the item, but get the same SKU must be unique error

Does any body have any ideas? I assume it should be possible to delete an item from the product list and re-create it?

If I cant fully delete the item is there a way for me to un-delete it? so I can then just update the profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why SKU still exists in your system after delete products. But you can solve your problem by execute SQL statement bellow:

```
DELETE * FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku='XXXX';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but is it safe to run a query like this on the database? Would it not leave orphaned records in the database?

Comment: Running delete query directly is not good, but in your case this is only way. Delete command will be CASCADE, don't worry about orphan records.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this appears to have resolved the problem and I can now add new products that re-use the previously deleted SKU's. I've also checked the categories and the item links appear to have disappeared.

Comment: One more question - Has any had experience doing this as a fix? and is this fix likely to cause problems in the future? How certain are you about the CASCADE removing all linked records?

Comment: I usually run this kind of command to delete products in batch mode before moving from development stage to live stage. You know, delete over 10000 product in admin screen is very slow. About CASCADE, if you see child tables of catalog_product_entity, you should see all reference key is CASCADE.